# How can I add spacing and alignment within and to an array of text?

Tags: arrays, alignment, text

How can I take a text array such as this:

```
 \[
 \left. \begin{array}{l}
 \textrm{Commonwealth}\\
 \textrm{vs}\\
 \textrm{Person on Trial}
 \end{array} \right\} \textrm{A matter of Debt}
 \]
```

Which produces this:

[image: Text Array example (centered)]

And force it to align to the left side of the page instead of being centered?

Additionally, how can I move the textrm `vs' further to the right so that it aligns below the letter`n' in `Commonwealth'?

Any help very greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it supposed to be within an equation?

Comment: No, this is not an equation.  The array is being used strictly for the tall right curly brace which is a common element in old legal documents I'm transcribing.

Comment: just use `$` not `\[` so it is at the left and use `tabular` not `array` so the entries are text.

Comment: Sorry to be dense but could you show an mwe for that?

Comment: Then you don't need an equation. There are other tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple solution with a `tabular` and package `delarray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{delarray}

\begin{document}
\mbox{}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}.{@{}c@{\,}}\}
Commonwealth\\
 vs\\
Person on Trial
 \end{tabular}A matter of Debt

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks Bernard!

Comment: ooh delarray I'd forgotten about that, who wrote that?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Guess who? (said Droopy) ;o)